# Populate html drop-down using data from postgresql database using Python-Flask

Tags: html, forms, postgresql, flask, drop-down-menu

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<form>
<select multiple="multiple" 
<option value="Hello">Hello</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using **postgresql** database in which I have table with one column and one row saying 'Hello'

I want to pull that data and display it as selection option in html form using **FLASK**.

Can anyone help me please,
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's actually opposite to the above posting,
I need data from database(postgresql) to be posted in select html form
not by using php but by using python-flask

Comment: Ah gotcha, flag removed!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to read Flask's [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) to learn some basic.

Here is a minimal application that meets your needs.

*View function:*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    items = get_your_data_from_db()
    return render_template('index.html', items=items)
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<form>
<select multiple="multiple">
{% for item in items %}
<option value="{{ item.field_name }}">{{ item.field_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```